# Short address DALI-2

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, light-sensor, addressing, dali

I'm trying to write a complete algorithm for assigning short addresses to input devices on a DALI bus. At the start I don't know how many input devices are installed on a DALI bus.
The procedure in order is: INITIALISE, RANDOMISE and then SEARCHADDRH(data), SEARCHADDRM(data), SEARCHADDRL(data), before doing PROGRAM SHORT ADDRESS (data). The PROGRAM can be done only if randomAddress is equal to searchaddress. For the search, how can I do for find searchaddress equal to randomAddress if I have 2^24 possible combinations?  It's too long. Is there a possible operation for doing this in a short time?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `COMPARE` command. It works by comparing the `randomAddress` (which is very likely unique per each recipient of the `RANDOMISE`) with the `searchAddress` (that you control throw `SEARCHADDRH`/`SEARCHADDRM`/`SEARCHADDRL`). When the control gear has `initializationState` `ENABLED`, then IEC 62386-102:2014 says that it shall:

- if `randomAddress` ≤ `searchAddress`: send `YES`
- in all other cases, send `NO`.

Comment: Yes , I know, but my questions are: you have to do a bynary search, right? And the COMPARE command gives an only answer in a loop? For example, could I write a simple code like this? array_device[64]
for(i=0; i<len(array_device);i++){
min=0
max=2^24 – 1
medium_value=(min+max)/2 while(medium_value != random_address){ SEARCHADDRH(x) SEARCHADDRM(y) SEARCHADDRL(z) ret=COMPARE if(ret == “YES”){ max=medium_value
}else if(ret==”NO”){ min=medium_value
}else{ TIMEOUT “collision”
}
medium_value=(min+max)/2
}
PROGRAM SHORT ADDRESS (data) VERIFY SHORT ADDRESS (data) WITHDRAW }

Comment: @NicolaBellini - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules differ from typical forums. (b) You originally posted the above comment as a new *answer*, using the box below labeled "Your Answer". However it was clearly a reply to *this* answer and not the solution (answer) to your original question. Therefore I moved your post to here. (Please review the links I gave regarding the Q&A format of the site.) (c) Unfortunately you have hit some limits of the site. You are trying to include more proposed code and, as you see, the formatting/layout is removed in comments.

Comment: (continued) Also, a question should not be changed, after someone has answered the original question - otherwise readers will see an apparent mismatch where the answer does not seem to answer the (updated) question. (This is a situation referred to as a "chameleon question" i.e. it keeps changing.) Therefore adding your proposed code into the question now should be avoided, as it would make this answer look wrong. (There are complex approaches we can try to handle that kind of situation, but changing questions often deteriorate into an unsolved mess.) Let's see if this user above can help.

Comment: @NicolaBellini, that code is rather unreadable in its current, unformatted form and shape. If you cannot figure it out yet, try looking for some duplicate questions (there's plenty of resources about DALI addressing here on thisStackExchange) and re-read your copy of the standard. If that doesn't help, post a new question which clearly says what you're doing, what you're seeing, and what you expect to see.

Comment: @JanKundrát - Hi, I know the new code from the OP is rather unreadable and I didn't like moving it from the OP's non-answer that way. That deliberate lack of formatting is a limitation of comments :( But adding it into the question as an update would mean that your answer (to the original version of the question) may look like it's a non-answer and get downvoted, due to it not answering the then *updated* version of the question. I hope you see what I mean. || Your suggestion for the OP to post a new question (as you answered the original version) sounds fine. :)

Comment: My question is: How can I do (step by step, with commands and every loop) for match the randomAddress with searchAddress? With a bynary search with COMPARE? The COMPARE is broadcast and gives one or more answer once ?

Comment: @NicolaBellini: All the information that you need are in the reply above, and in other answers to similar questions on this site. Have you read & understood them? A good question for this site is "I'm trying to do FOO. I tried A, B and C, and I don't understand why I'm getting X instead of Y. The docs says BLAH, which makes me think that BAR should do Z." If you asked that way, it would be clear that you put some effort into trying to solve the problem on your own. I'm sorry, but I'm not seeing that effort here. Instead, you're essentially asking for someone to do your job, for free.

Comment: You might be missing the fact that in DALI, a NO response is no response, so although COMPARE is broadcast, you should only see one clean YES response since all the other control gears stay silent. Unless you have two or more with the same random address, then you would get a collision response. Also see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/529867/2110